# Nivo Slider jQuery plugin Not installed

Tags: 7

I´m trying to install [Nivo Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) to my website. I was following this tutorial from the official plugin website.

I have the folder "all" an inside it I have "libraries", "modules", and "themes". I extracted the FlexSlider-master.zip in my libraries folder, and rename it to "nivo-slider".

The second step was install the extension from the url drupal/project/nivo_slide without drush, download the folder an upload to my server in modules/.

I have clear the cache but the problem persist.

Can someone help me? I can´t upload pictures or links with less than 10 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's drupal 8, which sounds like it, your libraries folder needs to be **outside** of the sites folder. Where you main Drupal stuff is, like the modules folder.

ex: Needs to be `drupal/libraries` and not `drupal/sites/libraries`

The `drupal/sites/libraries` is only for Drupal 7.

Comment: Did you install [jQuery update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update)? and selected a version higher than 1.7?

Comment: Yes, I work with Jquery 1.8

Comment: I resolve the problem getting the folder libraries of other project. Maybe the repository has a mistake or somethink like that...